# Handle nested SQL statements in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-administration, sqlperformance

My procedure has large query syntax, many "nested if else" when I create it on one SQL Server I get this error:

> Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.

but when I create that on another server, it is created without error. I know the procedure has poor performance but why that is created correctly on another server

Does it depend on server config or database feature ?

Comment: I think the bigger issue here is that seeing this error on _any_ version of SQL Server might indicate poor code design.  You might want to include the offending code in your question.

Comment: Please, we need to see the code qo we can make it run on every instance. Edit your question and add the code please.

Comment: Please edit your question and fix your typo then provide more info your environment, also attach your query, what do you mean by "another server"? you mean another sql server instance or another version of MSSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**when i create that on another server,that is created without error**

Reason is that the two version is not same . I think you 1st server is older than 2012sp1 that's why you got that error. you can check this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2958429/bugs-that-are-fixed-in-sql-server-2012-service-pack-2)

Comment: While this may answer the technical question, it is not really a fix for the underlying error.

Comment: thanks , yes exactly ,i check the version of my SQL Server

it is "Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64)"

The stored procedure is created correctly after this version,but in this version this sp can not create

Comment: but the version is higher than 2012sp1

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3058865/sql-server-2014-service-pack-1-release-information